# How i can correct an spread error, of rows to columns?

Tags: r, tidyr

iam triying to pass rows to columns with the function spread (tidyr) and gives the next error: Error in `spread()`:
! Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.

I have this data frame

| Month | pH |
| --- | --- |
| January | 7.2 |
| January | 5.2 |
| February | 4.0 |
| February | 7.3 |
| March | 7.1 |
| March | 5.0 |

Are about 8.000 values of pH, January to december, are aprox per month 700 but are diferent long.

I want this

| January | February | March |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7.2 | 4.0 | 7.1 |
| 5.2 | 7.3 | 5.0 |

Answer (score 0):

This happens because there is no unique identifier, also `spread` is deprecated, so you can use `pivot_wider`.

### Data

```
data <-
tibble::tribble(
      ~Month, ~pH,
   "January", 7.2,
   "January", 5.2,
  "February",   4,
  "February", 7.3,
     "March", 7.1,
     "March",   5
  )
```

### Code

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(Month) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Month,values_from = pH)
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
     id January February March
  <int>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     7.2      4     7.1
2     2     5.2      7.3   5
```

Comment: In row 1, can't recycle input of size 744 to size 672.
Backtrace:
 1. ... %>% unnest()
 2. tidyr::unnest(.)
 4. tidyr:::unnest.data.frame(...)
 5. tidyr::unchop(data, any_of(cols), keep_empty = keep_empty, ptype = ptype)
 6. tidyr:::df_unchop(cols, ptype = ptype, keep_empty = keep_empty)
 7. purrr::reduce(x_sizes, unchop_sizes2)
 8. purrr:::reduce_impl(.x, .f, ..., .init = .init, .dir = .dir)
 9. tidyr (local) fn(out, elt, ...)

Comment: It appears that error

Comment: I updated with another solution